# I do not want to show alert message when I prevent users pressing Ctrl and P

Tags: javascript, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I hide JavaScript's behavior from the user when I prohibit printing?
I was able to prevent the print button from being pressed on that web page by writing the following inside the head tag of the html file:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    document.onkeydown = keys;
    function keys()
    {
  　switch (event.keyCode)
       {
        case 82: // Ctrl + R
        if( event.ctrlKey )
        {
        event.keyCode = 0;
        return false;
        }
        case 80: // Ctrl + P
        if( event.ctrlKey )
        {
        event.keyCode = 0;
        alert('Hello.'); //If this code was none, Ctrl and P can be executed,
        return false;
        }
        break;
       }
    }
    </script>
```

This Ctrl+P is strange.
If I do not intervene something before

```
   return false;
```

such as

```
   alert();
```

the print screen will appear.

However like

```
    case 82: // Ctrl + R
    if( event.ctrlKey )
    {
    event.keyCode = 0; 
    return false; //without alert codes,this code can be executed.
    }
```

The script can be executed without alert codes.It is strange thing for me.

If an alert message is seen, the user will easily see that it is running in JavaScript or something, so if possible, I want something invisible to the user side;
What should I do?
Do I have to show alert message to user like:

```
    alert('Please do not print.');
```

I want some help.Thanks.

Comment: FWIW, this won't prevent me clicking on File > Print...

Comment: ... or from opening the developer console and typing `window.print()`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest and most standard way to implement this is with [`Event#preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault):

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.key === 'p' && e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault()
    }
})
```

Comment: Sorry this is not working. The browser I set is Internet Exploer 11. So maybe this code can work with other browser. Thanks.

Comment: "The browser I set is Internet Explorer 11" — any special reason? Internet Explorer 11 is officially dead as of earlier this year. https://www.theverge.com/2022/6/15/23167121/microsoft-internet-explorer-end-of-support-retirement

Comment: Yes.I have to use IE11 browser.Maybe on other browser I can realize natural code without using alert.